# How to group javascript array values

Tags: javascript

this is my data

```
['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','aaa','bbb','eee','ccc','aaa']
```

the output i want

```
[
['aaa','aaa','aaa'],
['bbb','bbb'],
['ccc','ccc'],
['ddd'],
['eee']
]
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty simple use for `reduce` to group an array, and `Object.values` to get the result you wanted.

```js
const input = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','aaa','bbb','eee','ccc','aaa']

const output = Object.values(input.reduce( (acc,i) => {
    acc[i] ??= []
    acc[i].push(i);
    return acc;
},{}))

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You might want to link to some documentation particularly to "logical nullish assignment" which isn't that well known.